# Is it possible to have different color.xml for different theme?

Tags: android, styles, android-theme

I am working on different themes in a single application. e.g I have a login screen and for all of the themes, I want to set different background and textcolor.

I am fetching the color from color.xml. so it possible that I should define background and text color with the same key and with different color code for all the themes.

```
*Theme 1
*Theme 2
*Theme 3
```

and only 1 color.xml file with

```
 <color name="background">#000000</color>
 <color name="textcolor">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Now I want to use different color codes for all the themes. How can this be possible..

Any idea ???

Comment: You need to change theme(colours) at runtime?

Comment: No. But you can have different themes using different colors. Like: theme1_background, theme2_background, ...

Comment: yes, sort of. But I dont want to make it code base. I want to change it in styles. Can I define it in style like: for Theme 1 use color_1.xml, for theme2 use color_2.xml ??

Comment: @BobMalooga I didn't get you..

Comment: Make each theme use different colors. These colors will be defined in the colors.xml file with different names. So each theme (say themeX) might refer its own colors (themeX_someColor)

Comment: Is it possible to create different color.xml files (like color_theme1.xml, color_theme2.xml) and I will pick respective color xml file according to theme selected ?

Comment: you cant use same name file for it and also same string key for color

Comment: If android studio made different colors file ( like different strings.xml file for different languages )..... then it would be better for change theme easily.......

Comment: @Kanika how did you figure it out ? I am kind middle of same situation, would you help ?

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved with the following approach.
First you create an attrs.xml file in which you define the color identifiers.
Like that:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="myColor" format="color" />
</resources>`

Then you create a base_theme.xml file in which you do not define the colors but the attributes. Like that:

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">?attr/myColor</item>
</style>
```

Finally you create every theme by extending base theme and defining your specific colors,
like that:

```
<style name="Theme1" parent="BaseTheme">
    <item name="myColor">#123456</item>
</style>
```

It is worth mentioning that every theme can be in separate file. As a result we can have separate colors per theme. Basically now you can define just your colors in every theme